# How to change default name of buttons in datatable plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, excel, datatable

I am using datatables plugin for by displaying data in my html page.
I have a requirement where I want to export the data inside the datatable.

Datatable supports this functionality by some plugins and a example can be seen [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html).

what I get on screen is that the export buttons with the fixed default names like below

[image]

I want to change the default names to custom names. eg. "Excel" to "Export to Excel"

How can I do that?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    } );
} );
```

In the above code if I change the default names , then my functionality breaks because datatable recognizes the functionality of button by its name. Is there any property which I should use which will help me achieve what I want or any other way out?

Comment: please find [this link](https://datatables.net/reference/option/buttons.buttons.text) it'll help you

Comment: Looks like the link that @Curiousdev gave works for you. For another workaround,  I think datatable works with classes. The excel button has "buttons-excel" class if you inspect the element. You can change the child span's text with jquery maybe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the new version of DataTables;

```
buttons: [
   { 
      extend: 'copy',
      text: 'Copy to clipboard'
   }
]
```

Here is the [example from documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/buttons.buttons.text#Examples).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
buttons: [
   { 
      sExtends: 'copy',
      text: 'Custom text'
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
buttons: [
    { extend: 'excel', text: 'Export to excel' }
]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please provide some more information, why this code answers the question.